# Value from GET parameters in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have the link like below:

```
    http://localhost/Matrix/details.php?imgi=4
```

But i want to get the value of imgi in javascript i.e 4. Any solutions?

Comment: Duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/901144/5447994).If interested, check my [blog post](http://smal.me.pn/hEj) for shorter version.

Comment: Please refer the below answer from stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/a/979997/2123545